# Does the ask pattern work with Akka IO actors?

Tags: scala, akka

Say I have an IO Actor `connection` capable of sending and receiving messages over TCP. In my actor, I ask the other side of the connection for a response:

```
 connection.ask(ByteString("stuff")).collect {
    case Received(response) => log.debug(response.utf8String)
 }
```

It appears that with this code the ask future times out, and instead the containing actor receives the raw message outside of the ask pattern.

Can you use the ask pattern with Akka IO actors? If not, why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the architecture in detail, but here's how I would explain it to myself:

The problem with Akka IO connector actors here is that they don't work in a request-response manner. And if you think about it - that makes sense, because TCP is not a request-response protocol. TCP doesn't even have a notion of *message*. From programmer's perspective TCP connection is just a pair of continuous byte streams - one in each direction. That's it.

Akka IO is a minimal actor layer on top of network protocols, so it's not surprising that it mimics this behaviour. When TCP actor receives some data from the network, it only knows one thing - that it should send a `Received` message to the actor that originally sent the `Connect` message. That's all. It has no idea that the data it received from the network is somehow related to the data that you sent earlier.

Adding to all of that, `ask` pattern works only under assumption that when you send message `A` to some actor, it will respond with the message `B` by sending it exactly to the *sender* of message `A`. As we already know, TCP actor doesn't do that - it simply sends everything to the sender of original `Connect` message.

The reason why this assumption is required is that `ask` pattern actually creates some sort of a "phantom" actor that is set as the *sender* of the message sent using `ask`. This "phantom" actor will then receive the response and invoke all the callbacks registered on the `Future`. As a side note - be aware that those callbacks are invoked completely independently of the sending actor, i.e. they may run concurrently to it!

So, I would finally conclude that the `ask` pattern used like this will *not* work with Akka IO, because it's simply too low level for such an abstraction. If you still want it, you need to create you own layer of abstraction on top of Akka IO, e.g. some simple intermediate actor that covers TCP connector actor and implements the request-response behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As an additional reference to @ghik's answer, here's roughly how I created an intermediate actor to enable the ask pattern for IO on the rest of my actors.

```
class IOAskHandlerActor(address: InetSocketAddress) extends Actor {
   override def receive = {
      // Connection setup code omitted    
      case Connected(remote, local) =>
         // other code omitted
         context become latch(sender())
   }

   def latch(connection: ActorRef): Receive = {
      case outgoing =>
         context become receiving(connection, sender())
         connection ! MySerializer.write(outgoing)
   }

   def receiving(connection: ActorRef, asker: ActorRef): Receive = {
      case Received(incoming) =>
         context become latch(connection)
         asker ! MySerializer.read(incoming)
   }
}
```

Instances of this class can be `ask`ed for responses. Note that I have only tested this with one simultaneous asker (which is my use case) and this probably doesn't work for multiple askers.